# Select title of column with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```js
      Title1     Title2
0       420        50
1       380        40
2       390        45
```

How can I get as output only the name of the title of the first column (Title1) without the values of the column? I've tried iloc but that doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df`is your dataframe, then the following should work:

```
first_col = df.columns[0]
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(df.columms)
lst[0]
```

It will give you the all the column name in a list... & first item fetched using indexing...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
data={"Title1":[10,20,30],"Title2":[100,50,30]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    print("---------")
    print("print of column:")
    print(df[col])
```

Result:
Intial df:

```
   Title1  Title2
0      10     100
1      20      50
2      30      30
```

first column name:

```
Title1
```

print of first column:

```
0    10
1    20
2    30
Name: Title1, dtype: int64
```

Second column name:

```
Title2
```

print of second column:

```
0    100
1     50
2     30
Name: Title2, dtype: int64
```